# How do I render dividers with *ngFor for tablet and phone views?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a big problem with my current front-end assignment. The designer built the following templates for the item display on a tablet and phone.

[Tablet view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhzSj.jpg)

[Phone view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gI4f.jpg)

As you can see, pairs of items are followed by a horizontal divider on a tablet except the last row of items. On a phone, each individual item is followed by a divider except the last item.

Here is the template excerpt:

```html
<div class="row" *ngIf="customer">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" *ngFor="let item of customer.items">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <img class="img-responsive product-thumbnail" [src]="item.itemImageUrl">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                <div class="item-heading">
                    <b>{{ item.title }}</b>
                </div>
                <div class="item-details">
                    Item: 
                    <b>#{{ item.style }}</b><br>
                    SKU: 
                    <b>{{ item.sku }}</b><br>
                    Size:
                    <b>{{ item.size }}</b><br>
                    Color:
                    <b>{{ item.color }}</b>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried solving this problem using *odd* and *last* from *ngFor* and CSS class visibility with media queries to no avail. If anyone has dealt with it successfully, please tell me what I need to do to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your current item div with an ng-container and use ngFor on the container. This will allow you to inject an hr every 2 items (tablet hr).

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="customer">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of customer.items; let isOdd = odd; let isLast = last">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <!-- Your other code -->
      <!-- This is the hr at the mobile size (xs)
      <hr class="visible-xs" *ngIf="!isLast">
    </div>

    <!-- This is the hr at the tablet size (sm+)
    <div class="col-sm-12 visible-sm visible-md visible-lg" *ngIf="isOdd && !isLast">
      <hr>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

---

### Breaking down the code.

The first hr (mobile)

```
<hr style="display: none" [ngClass]="{'visible-xs': !isLast}">
```

From your design the last item in the list should not have an hr below it. The ngIf conditional makes sure that last hr does not render. You can use the `visible-xs` class on these hrs so they are only visible at the xs size.

---

The second hr (tablet)

```
<div class="col-sm-12 visible-sm visible-md visible-lg" *ngIf="isOdd && !isLast">
    <hr>
</div>
```

Same thing as the mobile, the last hr is not visible due to the condition in ngIf. You only render hrs after the odd items excluding the last item. You can use the `visible-sm visible-md visible-lg` classes to display the hr at the appropriate sizes (note: you could also use `hidden-xs`, but I wasn't sure what sizes you needed for this hr)

Here is a [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/llai-bootstrap-hr-layout?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) demoing this.

Comment: I was close to your code in my failed attempt. Thanks a lot for showing the correct way!

Comment: @AndreKuzmicheff glad I could help!